# Issue running Update on Server 13.04

Tags: 13.04, server, apt

I'm running into an issue when trying a `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

It fails with the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing systemd-services (--configure):
  Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
  reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Errors were encountered while processing:
  systemd-services
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I try to do a force install of systemd-services, and get the exact same error

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop trying to force things. `dpkg` is telling you that the package is in **very bad state** and you should **reinstall it**. The best way to do so is using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get --reinstall install systemd-services
```

The first command will clear the package cache so when you run the next it downloads from the servers the package again.